# Probability theory- Does modern probability theory give a clear and unambiguous answer to the MontyHall problem?

Tags: probability

The Monty Hall problem is a classic in probability theory, and the discussion about it seems endless. But does the modern theory of probability (Kolmogorov) answer this clearly and unambiguously? If yes, how? If not, why?
P.s. The op does not know any probability theory.

Comment: The Kolmogorov axiomatization says nothing about goats and cars. Classical probability theory, together with the choice of a suitable model, settles the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, elementary probability theory has shown that the probability of winning the game after switching is $2/3$. See [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem#Solutions) for multiple proofs, or check a variety of youtube videos.

Comment: So it can be explained clearly without having to refer to the Kolmogorov axioms?

Comment: Explanations do not usually resort to explicitly invoking axioms, no. I don't really know what the Kolmogorov axioms are, as opposed to any other probability axioms, but the proofs are based on the definitions of an introduction to probability class.